# Using PROGMEM in constructor

Tags: c++, progmem, memory

Is it safe to use PROGMEM variable like dynamically allocated memory (a pointer to PROGMEM variable which is out of scope).

I need this so I can generate a variable size (before compilation), constant values, lookup array stored in flash.

Working example:

```
class Ex_class {
  public:
    Ex_class(int table_size, int value_range) {
      int flash_table[table_size + 1] PROGMEM;
      _ex_table = flash_table;
      for (int i = 0; i <= table_size; i++) {
        _ex_table[i] = random(value_range);
      }
    }

    int get_value(int index) const { return _ex_table[index]; }

  private:
    int* _ex_table;
};

void setup() {
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ex_class ex_object(5, 50);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    Serial.print(i); Serial.print(": "); Serial.println(ex_object.get_value(i));
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: I am amazed this even compiles... You cannot assign a value to a PROGMEM variable, the only thing you can do with PROGMEM is store compile-time constants. And you cannot dereference a pointer to PROGMEM with `*` nor `[]`, you need one of the `pgm_read_*()` macros.

Comment: The compiler cannot run "Ex_class ex_object(5, 50);" at compile time.

Comment: I am surprised too, but it actually works.

Comment: It's probably getting the data from RAM that was allocated (and deallocated) in the stack.

Comment: You are right, it stored a new variable in the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I could get to what you are trying to do is this:

```
template <size_t table_size> struct Ex_class {
  int get_value(int index) const {
    return pgm_read_word(&_ex_table[index]);
  }
  int _ex_table[table_size];
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  static PROGMEM const Ex_class<5> ex_object = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(ex_object.get_value(i));
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

`avr-nm` and `avr-objdump` confirmed that the object lives indeed in the
text section of the program. Please note that:

- The object is `PROGMEM const`. It would make no sense to try to put in
  PROGMEM anything that is not constant.
- The object is allocated statically. It can be either a global or a
  static local, but not an automatic local like in your example.
- I am using [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) here. I know no other way to
  statically initialize an array of variable length. If you have an
  idea, I would be interested to know though.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing I can think of is initializing the flash variables separately (because they need to be calculated) and then putting the pointers to them in an array. It shouldn't be a problem since the flash is read-only.